# compile with gsl with an existing makefile

Tags: makefile, gsl

i have a makefile for some code library i'm using and now i've added to that code some code that uses gsl. i'm not so sure how and what to add to the makefile (which i wat to keep since it's invoking boost as well) that would invoke gsl.

This is my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
ARCH = -mtune=generic
#   ARCH = -march=core2
#   ARCH = -march=native


COFLAGS = $(ARCH) -O3 -pipe
CXXFLAGS = -Wall $(COFLAGS)

PROGRAMS = getData analyzeData
BOOSTFLAGS = -I .
OPENMP = -fopenmp -DSUPPORT_OPENMP

all: $(PROGRAMS)
getData: getData.cpp common.o parse.o common.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) getData.cpp common.o parse.o -o getData
analyzeData:  analyzeData.cpp common.o parse.o parameters.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BOOSTFLAGS) $(OPENMP) estimateCrossReplicatesExpression.cpp common.o parse.o parameters.o -o analyzeData

parameters.o: parameters.cpp parameters.h
parse.o: parse.cpp parse.h
common.o: common.cpp common.h

clean:
    rm *.o $(PROGRAMS)
```

Comment: Do you know how to compile the new code on the command line? Do you know where the gsl directory (containing the gsl headers) is?

Comment: yeah, i have the full path to gsl. i haven't tried to compile my code on the command line however, because it relies on several other libraries so i prefer to use the makefile.

Comment: I don't have gsi to play with, so I suggest you write a "HelloWorld" that uses gsi, and try building it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

In case GSL is installed on the default path (/usr/local/include/gsl) on your system, the compilation command for a source file "example.c" would be

**gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include -c example.c**

The library is installed as a single file, libgsl.a. A shared version of the library libgsl.so is also installed on systems that support shared libraries. The default location of these files is /usr/local/lib. If this directory is not on the standard search path of your linker you will also need to provide its location as a command line flag.

To link against the library you need to specify both the main library and a supporting cblas library, which provides standard basic linear algebra subroutines. A suitable cblas implementation is provided in the library libgslcblas.a if your system does not provide one. The following example shows how to link an application with the library,

**$ gcc -L/usr/local/lib example.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm**

The option -lm links with the system math library. On some systems it is not needed.

Thus, you need to specify the gsl specific flags in your compile command. Update the Makefile accordingly.